# How to get O365 License expiration dates using Graph Api

Tags: office365api, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, office365-restapi

I need to know when my O365 licenses will be expired using O365 APIs.

I am using this REST call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=assignedLicenses,assignedPlans,id

which returns all my assigned licenses and assigned plans. but does not tell me when my licenses will be expired.

Is there any way for me to get this info using an API?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Graph API does not expose license expiration dates. The API covers license assignment, but not subscription lifecycle management. There is no way to get that info using an API.

Comment: Hi Henry - I'd be interested to understand your scenario around why you need access to this information.  This will help us prioritize exposing this in the Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! we will need this info to know when our employees' O365 licenses are going to expire and do the necessary actions to renew/buy new licenses. and also be able to manage licenses when new employees join ir leave the company. We have an internal web app which tracks all Microsoft licenses but O365 licenses are a bit different and we need to call some API to give us all our employees' license details and know when they are going to expire and what not.